# How do I fix this Sublime SFTP parsing error?

Tags: sublimetext3, sftp

Error parsing server config file untitled:
No JSON object could be decoded

I can still connect to the server after pressing OK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've been really silly and accidentally saved an empty file in the sftp_servers folder. sigh.